# What to do to improve bass resonance in mid sized piano?

Tags: piano, acoustics

Got myself a mid sized piano (110 height). Great tone in upper area but lower area is collapsed compared to a full size piano (of course).

Has anyone tried to reduce acoustic shortcuts in smaller pianos, using bass-reflex or passive radiators?

**UPDATE**

Not that it covers my original idea about fixing the shortcut in the resonance-plate but good advices at:

https://www.pianobuyer.com/article/how-to-make-a-piano-room-sound-grand/

- Avoid wall-to-wall placement (avoid fluttering)
- Explore open angle to back wall
- Open doors to adjacent rooms

Comment: Where it is in the room will also have an important bearing.

Comment: Yeah I mean putting it in a corner might be your best bet

Comment: Have you tried playing with top open or the front panel off?

Comment: Thanks, found many hints at https://www.pianobuyer.com/article/how-to-make-a-piano-room-sound-grand/ that I'll start off with.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit overkill but some may find it of interest..

*A* solution could be to pick the sound of the piano, EQ it in order, for instance to boost a bit the bass, and broadcasted in the room thanks to very clean loudspeakers...

If the electronic broadcast part bothers you, or if you want to add a bit of *caché* to your room you can also use an [acoustic resonator](https://www.la-voix-du-luthier.com/) ;).

Comment: Ah, an acoustic resonator could be it! Very interesting! :)

Comment: @Teson I am sure you will have more chance / easier time, playing with the room and panels, but I thought it was worth mentioning. Good luck!